# Straightforward exercise on relations and partitions

Tags: solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition on a set $A$, and define a relation $\sim$ on $A$ by:
$x \sim y \Leftrightarrow$ $x$ and $y$ belong to the same set $P \in \mathcal{P}$.
Check that $\sim$ really is an equivalence relation.

Is this just as straightforward as this?

(i) Reflexivity: $x \sim x \Leftrightarrow$ $x$ and $x$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$
(ii) Symmetry: if $x$ and $y$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$, then $y$ and $x$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$, so if $x \sim y$ then $y \sim x$
(iii) Transitivity: if $x$ and $y$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$ and $y$ and $z$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$, then $x$ and $z$ belong to the same subset $P \in \mathcal{P}$. So if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$ then $x \sim z$.

It seems very straightforward, but perhaps I have misunderstood the complexity. Also, the definition of "partition" seems a bit more "oral" than written with symbols...

I really hope I have not made a duplicate now! The question is if this "checks out", i.e. a solution verification...

Comment: Your proof is correct. You may "mathematize" it more by replacing sentences by mathematical symbols, but the latter are ultimately only shortcuts to say the same things, so that it is perfectly fine as is (unless it is required by your professor).